# Queues in a Linked List

Tags: python, linked-list, queue

I am trying to implement Queues in my LinkedList, I already did my Stack implementation after awhile now I am getting this error whenever I try to test out my queues.

```
C:\Python33\python.exe "C:/Users/koopt_000/Desktop/College/Sophomore Semester 2/Computer Science 231/Chapter5/palindrome.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/koopt_000/Desktop/College/Sophomore Semester 2/Computer Science 231/Chapter5/palindrome.py", line 33, in <module>
    isPalindrome('a')
  File "C:/Users/koopt_000/Desktop/College/Sophomore Semester 2/Computer Science 231/Chapter5/palindrome.py", line 12, in isPalindrome
    return sameSequence(forward, reverse)
  File "C:/Users/koopt_000/Desktop/College/Sophomore Semester 2/Computer Science 231/Chapter5/palindrome.py", line 27, in sameSequence
    ch1 = q.dequeue()
  File "C:\Users\koopt_000\Desktop\College\Sophomore Semester 2\Computer Science 231\Chapter5\MyQueue.py", line 65, in dequeue
    tempNode = self.head(0)
TypeError: 'ListNode' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is my ListNode Class:

```
class ListNode(object):

    def __init__(self, item = None, link = None):

        '''creates a ListNode with the specified data value and link
        post: creates a ListNode with the specified data value and link'''

        self.item = item
        self.link = link
```

Here is the code which is labeled 'Palindrome' which basically tests out both my Stack (Already completed) and my Queues(Which I am having trouble with).

```
from MyQueue import Queue
from MyStack import Stack
import string

#------------------------------------------------------------

def isPalindrome(phrase):
    forward = Queue()
    reverse = Stack()
    extractLetters(phrase, forward, reverse)
    return sameSequence(forward, reverse)

#------------------------------------------------------------

def extractLetters(phrase, q, s):
    for ch in phrase:
        if ch.isalpha():
            ch = ch.lower()
            q.enqueue(ch)
            s.pushItem(ch)

#------------------------------------------------------------

def sameSequence(q, s):
    while q.size() > 0:
        ch1 = q.dequeue()
        ch2 = s.pop()
        if ch1 != ch2:
            return False
    return True


print(isPalindrome('CooperepooC'))
```

Now here is my Queue class, now before you ask about " What is with the 'a' in your size function?" I literally have no idea what to put there. Anyways, I tried to implement most of my stuff I did from my stack class into this but it isn't working. Could anyone help me rearrange my queue class to make it work?

Here is my queue class:

```
from ListNode import ListNode
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Queue:

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------

    def __init__(self):

        self.head = None

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------

    def size(self):

        '''return number of items in the queue

        pre: none

        post: returns number of items in the queue'''

        return self.size

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------

    def enqueue(self, item):

        '''insert x at end of queue

        pre: none

        post: x is added to the queue'''

        tempNode = ListNode(item)
        tempNode.link = self.head

        self.head = tempNode

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------

    def front(self):

        '''return first item in queue

        pre: queue is not empty; IndexError is raised if empty

        post: returns first item in the queue'''

        return self.head[0]

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------

    def dequeue(self):

        '''remove and return first item in queue

        pre: queue is not empty; IndexError is raised if empty

        post: removes and returns first item in the queue'''

        if self.emptyList():
            raise IndexError("The list is empty so we cannot pop from it.")

        else:
            tempNode = self.head(0)
            self.head = self.head.link
            return tempNode

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

    def emptyList(self):

        return self.head == None


#----------------------------------------------------------------------

    def size(self):

        '''post: returns the number of elements in the stack'''

        return len('a')
```

If anyone could help me write out a working queue class it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to call a function 'head' but as far as I know, head is some variable, not a function.

```
tempNode = self.head(0)
```

Try

```
tempNode = self.head[0]
```

Comment: When I try this it states: Type Error: 'ListNode' object does not support indexing

Comment: So what is your ListNode?

Comment: I just added it, I knew I forgot to add something

Comment: So `self.head` is either `None`, or a ListNode, which is to say it only has `item` and `next`. Then leave out any mention of [0] or (0).

Comment: Oh, and you might want to `return tempNode.item` instead of `tempNode`

Comment: But then how would I go about popping the first node, like in a queue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72891/discussion-between-cooper-and-chw21).